# Triggering event on an element in memory when testing Backbone Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, integration-testing, jasmine

I am writing some integration tests for my Backbone views/models/collections. When I call `render` on my `View`, it simply renders a template to it's own `el` property, hence the html is simply stored in memory rather than on the page. Below is a simple model, and a view with a click event bound to a DOM element:

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/model'
});

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #remove': 'remove'
    }
    render: function () {
        var html = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
    },
    remove: function () {
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});
```

I am using Jasmine to write my tests. In the test below all I want to do is spy on the `remove` function to see if it is called when the click event is fired for the element `#remove` which is present in the template I pass to the view.

```
// template

<script id="tmpl">
    <input type="button" value="remove" id="remove"/>
</script>

// test

describe('view', function () {

    var view;

    beforeEach(function () {
        view = new view({
            template: $('#tmpl').html(),
            model: new model()
        });
    });

    it('should call remove when #remove click event fired', function () {       
        view.$('#remove').click();

        var ajax = mostRecentAjaxRequest();
        expect(ajax.url).toBe('/api/model');
        expect(ajax.method).toBe('DELETE');
    });

});
```

However, as the `#remove` element is in memory, and it hasn't actually been added to the DOM, I'm not sure how you would simulate the click event. In fact I'm not even sure if it's possible?

It may seem a bit strange to want to do this in a test, but with my tests I am trying to test **behaviour** rather than **implementation**, and this way I don't care what is happening in between - I just want to test that if the user clicks `#remove` a `DELETE` request is sent back to the server.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is that `remove` method from the view is not being called? I created [demo](http://jsbin.com/ihabom/2/edit) where I call `click` on an element which is only in memory and it works as expected. Are you running your tests in a browser environment or in phantom.js?

Comment: FWIW, for testing the request to the server, I would recommend using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/docs/) for mocking it out. It has a fake server you can set up. It should be faster (and safer?) than actually letting your code send a real AJAX request during unit testing.

Comment: @DaveNichol it looks to me like he's using [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine-ajax) to stub out the ajax request, so no actual requests are being made. That's what the `mostRecentAjaxRequest` call is for

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you forgot to call `render()` on the view before `click()`ing the button. And the model needs to have an `id` or backbone won't actually try to make a delete call to the server. I've tested plenty of views just like that before with no problems.

I just ran a similar test against jasmine 2.0 and jasmine-ajax 2.0.

live code:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/api/model'
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click #remove': 'remove'
  },
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.template = options.template;
  },
  render: function () {
    var html = _.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(html);
  },
  remove: function () {
    this.model.destroy();
  }
});
```

specs:

```
describe("testing", function() {
  var view;

  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    view = new MyView({
      template: '<input type="button" value="remove" id="remove"/>',
      model: new MyModel({id: 123})
    });
    view.render();
  });

  it('should call remove when #remove click event fired', function () {
    view.$('#remove').click();

    var ajax = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    expect(ajax.url).toBe('/api/model/123');
    expect(ajax.method).toBe('DELETE');
  });
});
```